# Nodejs/Typescript error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have one class defined in separate file named spartan.ts and here it is how it looks:

```
class Spartan {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    test() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

module.exports = Spartan;
```

Then I am importing this to other file which looks like this:

```
var Spartan = require("../entities/spartan.ts");
var mySpartan = new Spartan("myName");
console.log(mySpartan.test())
```

My tsconfing.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

And than I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
        at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/U.../routeRepository.ts:2:15)
```

Comment: can you show the compiled .js file?

Comment: Looking at the exception stack trace, it looks like the `require` call is actually expecting a vanilla JavaScript file, and it fails because of the TypeScript type annotations. How do you build the project?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the ES2015 module syntax for importing/exporting instead, for example:

```
export class Spartan {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    test() {
        return this.name;
    }
  }
```

And then:

```
import { Spartan } from "../entities/spartan.ts";
let mySpartan = new Spartan("myName");
console.log(mySpartan.test())
```

Comment: Its just `export class`

Comment: Yeah, that's more concise. Updated. Thanks @Antoniossss.

Comment: I think export is not a problem since if I change a code and run it like this it is working:
class Spartan {
    test() {
        return "My name is";
    }
  }
module.exports = Spartan;

Comment: That's probably because there is no TypeScript syntax. In your original example, you're trying to `require` a TypeScript file which won't work because `require` expects a JavaScript file.

Comment: However, if I drop the constructor and variables declaration in Spartan class, it consoles log "My name is"'.

Comment: Can you provide more info about the context? How do you build the project, and how do you run it?

Comment: It is angular app that contains a server part. Not sure if it is enough info for you?